# SOQL date in week where clause

Tags: salesforce, apex, soql

I have a custom object with a `Date` field and I was wondering how you could query that object if that date field is within the current week (given that the week starts on Sunday and ends on Saturday). I was thinking of creating two functions that find the specific date for the first day of the week and last day of the week and just doing:

```
SELECT Id, MyObjectDate FROM MyObject WHERE MyObjectDate > getWeekStartDate(todaysDate) AND MyObjectDate < getWeekEndDate(todaysDate)
```

But I feel like there is an easier way. Any tips would be appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `toStartOfWeek` method to get Start date of week.Check [this](http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/dbcom_apex230/Content/apex_methods_system_date.htm).

The `toStartOfWeek` method returns the start of the week for the Date that called the method, depending on the context user's locale. For example, the start of a week is `Sunday in the United States locale`, and `Monday in European locales`.

```
  public Date WeekFrom {get; set;}
  public Date WeekTo {get; set;}
  .....
  WeekFrom = todaysDate.toStartofWeek();
  WeekTo = WeekFrom.adddays(6);

  SELECT Id, MyObjectDate FROM MyObject WHERE MyObjectDate > WeekFrom  AND MyObjectDate < WeekTo
```

Hope it helps you